# MV3 Native Messaging: How do you communicate with an already-running instance of the native host?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-native-messaging

I'm builing a Chrome extension with a native host and my goal is as follows...

- External application communicates with native host
- Native host communicates with extension

So far I have the extension and the native host working, however I noticed that connecting to the native host via the extension opens a new instance of the host, regardless of whether or not the host was already running. This is a problem as I'd like the host to run persistently in order to receive messages from an external application.

I tried different methods of connecting to the host including runtime.connectNative() and runtime.sendNativeMessage(), but they both produce the same behavior (starting new host instance). At this point I'm thinking of abandoning direct communication and using something more indirect like creating a local file and having the extension constantly read it, although I doubt that would work as the service worker gets killed after a certain time, and using the content script would make the extension laggy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This API doesn't work like this. You can expose your app on localhost port and let the extension use `fetch`. You can also split the native host in two parts: the first part used by `nativeMessaging` will be just a connector that looks for a running second part and forwards the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-use the `port` returned by `runtime.connectNative()` if you want to talk to the same native host instance. Every call to `runtime.connectNative()` or `runtime.sendNativeMessage()` will open a new instance of the native host.

```js
// background script (in chrome extension)

// save port as a global variable (so we can target the same instance of native host)
let port;

function sendMessage(yourMessage) {
  if (!port) {
    // this will run the first time to launch the native host, and save the connection to that instance in the port
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('yourNativeHostId');
  }

  port.postMessage(yourMessage);
}

sendMessage('message 1');
sendMessage('message 2');
sendMessage('message 3');

// ^ they should all be delivered to the same instance of native host
```